# Why is my Samba domain member connecting to domain controllers in a trusting domain?

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba

My problem is logspam. I have 2 Windows AD domains with Windows domain controllers.  Domain A has some Ubuntu/Samba domain members. I have no issue using accounts in domain A to log into the servers, no problem accessing folders shared from the Ubuntu hosts using AD credentials.  Domain B trusts Domain A (one way, intransitive).
ON DOMAIN B domain controllers, I am continually (between 2 and 8 times per minute) logging a event 4625 `An account failed to log on: Account name: LinuxA$@DomainA.dom status 0xC000006D` (unknown username)

Why is Samba trying to go there and how can I make it stop?

Ubuntu 20.04 / Samba 4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6

```
smb.conf:
[global]
        disable netbios = Yes
        domain master = No
        idmap gid = 10000-20000
        idmap uid = 10000-20000
        local master = No
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        realm = DOMAINA.DOM
        restrict anonymous = 2
        security = ADS
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        template shell = /bin/bash
        unix password sync = Yes
        winbind enum groups = Yes
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind use default domain = Yes
        workgroup = DOMAINA
        idmap config * : range = 10000-20000
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: Run a packet trace on one of the Samba DC's and see what it's doing.

Comment: DC's are windows, not Samba. Packet cap of Samba client to windows AD server shows the samba client is trying to connect and authenticate and is rejected as per the event log. It does not give me any clue as to why it is connecting, I assume that would happen after the successful authentication.